# Is it possible to modify the position of an helper text of a MatTextField in MatBlazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, razor-pages, matblazor

I have a `MatTextField` written as follows:

```
<MatTextField TValue="string" Label="Insert a value" @bind-Value="@txtValue" Required="true" HelperTextPersistent="true" HelperText="Please insert a value" HelperTextValidation="true"></MatTextField>
```

and, as a result, the value of the `HelperText` is positioned under the `MatTextField`:

[image]

I was wondering if it is possible to modify the position of the `HelperText` (for example, by placing it to the right of the `MatTextField`).